# Na programação, o que significam "raw mode" e "cooked mode"?

Tags: terminologia

Ao ler uma das respostas à ["*Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/912184) me deparei com os termos "*raw mode*" e "*cooked mode*":

> *I found this on another forum while looking to solve the same problem. I've modified it a bit from what I found. It works great. I'm running OS X, so if you're running Microsoft, you'll need to find the correct system() command to switch to **raw and cooked modes***.

Já pesquisei, mas não acho seus significados, possivelmente porque estão mais para gírias, e se traduzirmos para o nosso idioma ("modo cru" e "modo cozido"), perde-se ainda mais o sentido. O que eles significam?

Comment: Poderia fornecer links? Acho que esses termos precisam de mais contextualização. Jogados assim realmente têm pouco significado. :D

Comment: @LuizFelipe - https://qastack.com.br/programming/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed

Comment: @GabrielCavalcante esse site, assim como muitos outros, são gerados por tradutores automaticos, copiados de fontes do stackoverflow em inglês. Se olhar abaixo da pergunta tem um link escrito `source`. obs: A pergunta original foi removida do SOen.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu acho que a pergunta original é esta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/q/421860/7445826

Comment: @LuizFelipe sim, o tal qstack que esta gerando o link assim `https://stackoverflow.com/programming/<id>`, por isso não "navegou". Obs: link relacionado: [Confusion about raw vs. cooked terminal modes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13104460/1518921)

Answer (score 0):

O par *raw mode* e *cooked mode* é usado para descrever a forma que um [terminal recebe o input de caracteres](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/mit-scheme-9.2/mit-scheme-ref/Terminal-Mode.html). *Raw* é o contrário de *cooked*.

- Um terminal em *cooked mode*, ou em modo canônico, processa cada caractere internamente e passa tudo para o terminal quando o Enter é pressionado. Esse é o padrão, e por isso é chamado também de canônico.
- Já um terminal em *raw mode*, ou em modo não-canônico, os caracteres não são processados internamente e são mandados diretamente (de forma crua) pro terminal.

Essa terminologia *raw* ou cru é também usada em programação. Por exemplo, se você recebe um dado cru, ou *raw data*, quer dizer que esse dado não passou por nenhum tipo de sanitização, e que ainda precisa de tratamento para poder trabalhar com ele. Esse tratamento pode ser transformar strings em outros tipos de dado, pivotar uma tabela, entre outras coisas.